# How to connect Rosjava talker to a C++ Listener

Tags: ros, c++, talker, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a talker in in rosjava and have created a listener in C++ code. When I run the talker and the start the listener I see this on the talker screen...

May 11, 2012 2:53:01 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
WARNING: An exception was thrown by a user handler while handling an exception event ([id: 0x4b3ec2dd, /127.0.0.1:40815 :> /127.0.0.1:42634] EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected message MD5 fee433c609b213f85c484ba6dc0f8c7c != 74765c06a94b3265f1c21e7d818205cd)
org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected message MD5 fee433c609b213f85c484ba6dc0f8c7c != 74765c06a94b3265f1c21e7d818205cd
at org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionTrackingHandler.java:73)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:432)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:52)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:317)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected message MD5 fee433c609b213f85c484ba6dc0f8c7c != 74765c06a94b3265f1c21e7d818205cd
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
at org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher.finishHandshake(DefaultPublisher.java:179)
at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpServerHandshakeHandler.handleSubscriberHandshake(TcpServerHandshakeHandler.java:99)
at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpServerHandshakeHandler.messageReceived(TcpServerHandshakeHandler.java:69)
... 12 more

I know that the talker and listener are working correctly all in rosjava but when I try to connect it with C++ node I get this error. Roscore is running on localhost:11311. What am I missing here? It also fails when I do a rostopic echo chatter.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33804/how-to-connect-rosjava-talker-to-a-c++-listener/) by [mikegulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2336/mikegulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-11**:
Looks like the message checksums do not match. What message are you trying to send?

**Comment by [mikegulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2336/mikegulf/) on 2012-05-11**:
I tried doing custom messages at first but then checked by sending a string and it did the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message means that the Rosjava publisher is trying to publish a message to a topic on which the C++ listener already listens, but the publisher's message type doesn't match the subscriber's message type. This can have two reasons:

1. Publisher and subscriber use different message types (e.g., one uses `std_msgs/String` and the other `std_msgs/Int8`).
2. Both use the same message type, but were built with different versions of it.

To debug (1), you can do the following:

- start a new roscore (!)
- start the subscriber
- do a `rosnode info` on the subscriber
- repeat the same for the publisher (after restarting the roscore) and see whether subscription and publication match up

To debug (2), you can

- make sure that your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `ROS_ROOT` are set up correctly
- rebuild your message package, if you are using custom messages
- rebuild your subscriber and your publisher (that way you know that both used the same environment variables when they were build)

I don't have any experience with the newest rosjava build system using gradle, but before the switch to gradle, it usually also helped to do the following, then rebuild the rosjava nodes:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/ ~/.ros/rosjava/
(cd $(rosstack find rosjava_core) && hg clean --all)
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikegulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2336/mikegulf/) on 2012-05-17**:
Thanks for the tips. It turned out I was sending one type of message and wanting to receive a different one. Once I got things aligned and was sending the proper message I was good. I appreciate your help.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-21**:
Glad to help! Please mark the answer as correct (check box to the left).